# Invalid operands of types int* and int[] to binary operator+

Tags: c++, matrix, types

Actually i am trying to sum elements from an int matrix in a certain pattern, but when I attempt to do this, it says that var s is a pointer??

```
int matrix[50][50];
//Initialization of matrix before
int k = n / 2;
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {

        for (int j = i; j < n + 1 - i; j++)
        {
             s = s + matrix[j, i] + matrix[j, n + 1 - i]; //line 10
        }

    }
    s += matrix[k, k];
```

On line 10  i am getting error: invalid operands of types 'int*' and 'int [50]' to binary 'operator+'
on line 14 : error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'

Comment: `[j, i]` isn't the correct syntax; you almost certainly want `[j][i]` or similar.

Comment: oh, my bad. I was struggling with Pascal's syntax tho )

Comment: no problem, please mark the answer below with the check mark if it correctly resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct one: `s = s + matrix[j][i] + matrix[j][n + 1 - i];`

Comment: That line definitely wouldn't work in Python either (NumPy, yes).

Comment: @iz_ the question is tagged `C++`, not `Python`.  The semi-colons should have been a clue.

Comment: @MarkRansom There was an edit; the answer used to read "Line 10 seems like a python line, not a C++ one :)"

Comment: With the original syntax you're using a comma operator, which only dereferences one of the two dimensions.